# Android alternative to long press action?

Tags: android, listview, long-press

Are there alternative to long press action?

I use long press in a listview to allow the user to edit the long pressed item in the listview.

To add a item i have a + (plus) icon in the toolbar.

To select the item the user can click/touch the item in the listview.

What worries me that the user can't find out how to edit a item (in other words that he should use long press to edit).

Putting a little label on every listview isn't nice either and mostly documentation isn't read.

Comment: Why you don't just use single click to edit the listview item and long click to select it?This style is used by most apps, so many people know how to use it.

Comment: @Dejvid mainly because select is used more frequently compared to the seldom used edit.

Comment: use showcase style indicate user to first time use that app..

Comment: @Okwan , well.. What if there is a text saying "Long click to edit" that is appeared only in the listview item that the user has selected by single click before?

Comment: @ZeroOne i had to look that one up because i didn't yet heard of showcase, but this looks the way to go. I'll give it a try. Cheers!